# Java Multithreaded Transactional service layer

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, hibernate

I have a task in which I have to implement a transactional service layer which manages multiple DAOs (those DAOs have only CRUD operations). In order to insert something into the database I have to use multiple DAOs, so I need to start a transaction.

I implemented a DAOManager class which implements the singleton pattern. This class has methods like getNewsDAO() which return only an instance of a DAO. Basically I can say that the DAOManager and all the DAO classes have a single instance per program.

I also implemented a ConnectionManager class which has 2 fields - a connection pool (used for retrieving a connection) and also a Connection field.

Basically, when I call a service layer method the flow is something like:

- get the connection from the connection pool and set it to the connection field inside the connection manager
- call all dao methods and pass them the connection field from the ConnectionManager by a method parameter

Every service class has a DAOManager field - which is singleton and a ConnectionManager field - the ConnectionManager is not a singleton. It has an instance per service class instance.

The problem comes when multiple threads use service classes. 
**A transaction is made by a single thread**  but I have to make sure that the same connection is not shared among threads.

Should I move the DAOManager and ConnectionManager in a thread local and make the ConnectionManager also singleton? Basically a single instance of DAOManager and ConenctionManager per thread and change from passing the connection to a method in DAO to setting it in an instance field of a DAO?

Or is my design already good practice?

Comment: not allowed to use spring

Comment: @NathanHughes There are many reasons not to use Spring - for cleaner workspace and lib dependencies; better customized features; better performance; etc. A framework isn't all-mighty.

Comment: @Alex: since the OP tagged this post with spring it seemed like he must be using it, which made me question why anyone using spring would recreate what it does already and think, maybe he doesn't know what it does or something. in this case it sounds like not making use of some existing solution (don't care if it's spring) is going to cost the OP extra time.